# Better way of implementing RewriteRule?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^featured/([^/]+)$ /pages/featured.php?game=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^featured/([^/]+)/$ /pages/featured.php?game=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^featured/ /pages/featured.php [L]
RewriteRule ^featured /pages/featured.php [L]
```

Example: I want user on this page

> https ://www.example.com/featured/tetris/

to be rewritten to this page

> https ://www.example.com/pages/featured.php?game=tetris

and the trailing slash doesn't matter.

Comment: In which way does it misbehave currently? (You can reduce the rules by optionalizing the `/?` trailing slash.)

Comment: @mario It gets messy when i have many pages and how do i optionalize?

Comment: With `?`. Note that the RewriteCond´s only guard the first RewriteRule.

Comment: @mario Thanks! Works and is better. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compact your rules into:

```
#         optional /gamename   slash
                      ↓         ↓
RewriteRule ^featured(?:/([^/]*)/?)?$ pages/featured.php?game=$1 [L]
```

That way you'll receive an empty `$_GET["game"]` if the request was just for `/featured` or `/featured/`. It will be populated for `/featured/whatever/` however.